# PHP string with accentuated characters not displayed properly

Tags: php, string

I am on PHP 5.2.17 (and I am no PHP expert). I was hoping the following would display properly:

```
<?php

$title = "Jérôme";
echo $title."<br>";

?>
```

But it displays:

> JÃ©rÃ´me

How can display my string properly? (The string is static)

Comment: See my ans , i have tested it and working perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to your HTML head:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

Note that you should have a [proper HTML doctype](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html) because browsers default to non utf8. You can do a simple test, like I did, this works:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<?php
$title = "Jérôme";
echo $title."<br>";
```

But the place for the meta tag is in the head tag. The HTML document should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>An XHTML 1.0 Strict standard template</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" 
        content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>

    <?php
    $title = "Jérôme";
    echo $title."<br>";
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

That **is standard**.

Comment: I don't have an HTML head, I call the php directly in my browser.

Comment: It's not really OK to **not** have an HTML <head> tag. Your HTML should have a <head> tag which should contain the <title> tag, and stuff like that. Anyway meta tag as shown above works for me, it should work for you too. The four-lines script I pasted, works. Try it ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" charset="utf-8" content="text/html;" />

<?php
$title = "Jérôme";
echo htmlspecialchars($title);
?>
```

Comment: And sometimes you have to force it form php. header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Answer (score 0):

Use php htmlentities function. see below example

```
$title = "Jérôme";
$title=  htmlentities($title);  
echo "<BR>Title :".$title."<br>";
```

Comment: With this, my source string is turned into J&Atilde;&copy;r&Atilde;&acute;me, but it is still not displayed properly.